# Efficient way to create collections from Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark data frame looks like:

```
ItemId  date   sale-amount
111    01-01  45
111    01-02  33
111    01-03  55
222    01-01  20
222    01-02  33
333    01-01  21
333    01-02  33
333    01-03   9
```

I want to create 3 separate dataframes to contain individual item with data and sale-amount,just like for item 111:

Df_111:

```
ItemId  date   sale-amount
    111    01-01  45
    111    01-02  33
    111    01-03  55
```

I know, I can do this by filtering all the item_id one by one on the original data frame, but is there any more efficient way?

Comment: Why do you want separate DataFrames? If you want to separate datasets the simplest (and efficient) solution can be writing to a partitioned source which supports partition pruning.

Comment: Because I want to apply a function on each item separated dataset.  just like group by function. Could you provide an example for this case?

Comment: Write with `partitionBy(...)` to format like parquet and parts you need.